# cross browser input buttons height and width

Tags: html, button, css, cross-browser

```
body #wrapper .button {
  background: #00b1ff; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00b1ff 0%, #006aff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00b1ff), color-stop(100%,#006aff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00b1ff 0%,#006aff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00b1ff 0%,#006aff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00b1ff 0%,#006aff 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #00b1ff 0%,#006aff 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b1ff', endColorstr='#006aff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  height: 45px;
  width: 118px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #223847;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

this seems to create some variations in the height/width across different browsers. any suggestions for getting pixel perfect height/width across browsers? gradient seems to be fine, I'm ok if it degrades into a solid color on older browsers.

Comment: Are you using a reset CSS? You may want to use one if not.

Comment: yes, I am using reset css, very similar if not exact to the on meyerweb. I tried that one too, no luck.

Comment: I can confirm most resets don't fix this. I hope someone who tests a reset.css before suggesting it has an anwer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Browser vendors often add specific styling. Things like borders, outlines, paddings and margins are differ between browsers. You can use a `reset css` to revert everything to default, or at least something known.

[See also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding, border-width, box-sizing, and font-family. All of these could potentially affect the overall width and height and browsers may have different default values.

Answer (score 0):

Hey first of all i'd suggest eric meyer css reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Second thing, if you plan your button to be redistributble, first of all remove pointless parent selector (leave .button standalone, so you can use it later). And for further development and good practise, try to make one default button, with core properties, with some basic colours, so you can later add new classes with only different color variants.